# invalid syntax when copying weight in pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I tried this:

```
model2.down1.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight.copy_(state_dict['layer1.0.conv1.weight'])
```

But I got below error message:

```
model2.down1.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight.copy_(state_dict['layer1.0.conv1.weight'])
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But my model output show its has "***down1.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight***"

[image]

Comment: Can you check the data type of `model2.down1.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not allow **numbers** to be attributes, so if you somehow create an object that has such attributes (it can be done only by low level function calls) you will not have access to them through dot notation (and this is why you get an invalid syntax error, rather than something like Attribute not found error).

You should instead take the `param` reference that you already have in your loop and do the copy

```
for name, param in model2.named_parameters():
  if name == 'down1.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight':
     param.copy_(state_dict['layer1.0.conv1.weight'])
```

Comment: OK. But I want to copy it to model2. But I don't see model2 in your code. How it willl get copied?

Comment: it is because of how **references** work in programming languages. param is a **reference** to an object **from model2**, thus changing it will affect model2

Comment: oh ...I see ..thanks!

Comment: I also Undertood from https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-access-to-a-layer-by-module-name/83797/4 that I could use model.string.[number].

Comment: again - not with integer names, this is forbidden in python